# pyPdf error invalid argument

Tags: python, file, pdf, pypdf, invalid-argument

I'm actually using pyPdf to open, read and write the content of a PDF file.

for that I use these lines of code :

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdf = PdfFileReader(file("/myPdfFile.pdf", "w+b"))
content = pdf.getPage(1).extractText()
print content
```

But it returns me this error and I don't understand exactly why

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 374, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 702, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Facing same issue on Newly Installed Amazon Server-Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the Python docs, the mode `'w+b'` opens and truncates the file to 0 bytes, while `'r+b'` opens the file without truncation.

Comment: Try again after recovering your pdf from backup - it is now 0 bytes long

Comment: No, I actually get the same error `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: When I try to open my PDF using the open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb') function I retrieve an empty file. I also don't understand why